# allow_relation in Django multiple database router

Tags: python, django, django-models

My generic DatabaseAppsRouter class:

```
class DatabaseAppsRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if settings.APPS_DATABASE_MAPPING.has_key(model._meta.app_label):
            return settings.APPS_DATABASE_MAPPING[model._meta.app_label]
        return DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if settings.APPS_DATABASE_MAPPING.has_key(model._meta.app_label):
            return settings.APPS_DATABASE_MAPPING[model._meta.app_label]
        return DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == settings.APP_QUES or obj2._meta.app_label == settings.APP_QUES:
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, model):
        if db == DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS:
            if not(model._meta.app_label in settings.APPS_DATABASE_MAPPING.keys()):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return settings.APPS_DATABASE_MAPPING.get(model._meta.app_label) == db
        return None
```

settings.py:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['rest_apis.database_app_router.DatabaseAppsRouter']
APPS_DATABASE_MAPPING = {APP_QUES: 'questions', 
                          'auth':'default'}
```

My doubt is, I can see the control coming inside `allow_migrate` and `db_for_write`, but is not coming inside `allow_relation` whenever I'm running `./manage.py migrate`

Is this a normal behaviour OR is there something wrong in my implementation ?

Comment: When should it call `allow_relation`? `manage.py migrate` usually doesn't create any objects, just the tables.

Comment: @knbk Then when does allow_relation comes to play ? and what happens if we dont provide this function in our DatabaseAppsRouter class ?

Comment: allow_relation is called when two related rows are saved - not when the fk constraint is created.